# Do Warlocks have the inital cantrips + 2 cantrips from the pacts at lvl 1?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, warlock

It says that I know 2 cantrips, because of the pact, but it isn't clear whether it's the 2 cantrips that you choose at level 1, or if I have +2 cantrips of my choice because of the pact.  Sorry for the idiot question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> You know two cantrips of your choice from lhe warlock spell list. You
>   learn additional warlock cantrips of your choice at higher levels, **as
>   shown in the Cantrips Known column of the Warlock table**. (PHB 107, emphasis mine)

The Class Feature Tables always contain the full amount of known spells, spell slots and the like. The text in the description of features *explains* these numbers further, not *expands* upon them (unless explicitly noted).

Thus you start with 2 cantrips known at level 1 as a warlock.